# Is there a way to overload += in python?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I know about the `__add__` method to override plus, but when I use that to override +=, I end up with one of two problems:

1. if `__add__` mutates self, then

   ```
   z = x + y
   ```

   will mutate x when I don't really want x to be mutated there.
2. if `__add__` returns a new object, then

   ```
   tmp = z
   z += x
   z += y
   tmp += w
   return z
   ```

   will return something without w since z and tmp point to different objects after `z += x` is executed.

I can make some sort of `.append()` method, but I'd prefer to overload `+=` if it is possible.

Comment: @tzot in a way, you're looking at the F'ing M.  ;-)

Comment: Do you imply that Josh is one of Python's manual writers? Sorry, I don't seem to understand what you mean, @BobStein-VisiBone .

Comment: @tzot I meant that Stack Overflow **is**, in large part, **The Manual** on Python. It was easier to find this page than [the one at docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html). Especially if you don't already know to search for `__iadd__` or the term "in-place" addition.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Yes. Just override the object's `__iadd__` method, which takes the same parameters as `add`. You can find more information [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

Comment: +1: Quote the documentation :-)

Comment: Do the types have to match? I.e., can I += two different types together if I want to? I keep getting exceptions, not sure if it's cause I'm doing it wrong or because it's not allowed ever. Docs are very weak on this.