# Is there a way to += and -= of an attribute call a instance's method?

Tags: python, class, getter-setter

**Question:** Is there a way to (`+=` and `-=`) call (`insert_knot` and `remove_knot`) in the class bellow?

**EDIT:** It's not duplicated from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728361/is-there-a-way-to-overload-in-python), cause I'm changing an attribute of the class (summing and subtracting), not the instance by itself. I mean, I sum/subtract an attribute and a method of the instance should be called.

```py
class SplineCurve:
    def __init__(self, knot_vector: Tuple[float]):
        self.knot_vector = knot_vector

    @property
    def degree(self) -> int:
        return self.__degree

    @property
    def knot_vector(self) -> Tuple[float]:
        return tuple(self.__knot_vector)

    @degree.setter
    def degree(self, new_value: int):
        if new_value == self.degree:
            return
        if new_value > self.degree:
            self.increase_degree(new_value - self.degree)
        else:
            self.decrease_degree(self.degree - new_value)
        self.__degree = new_value

    @knot_vector.setter
    def knot_vector(self, new_value: Tuple[float]):
        new_value = list(new_value)
        new_value.sort()  # Shouldn't be here, only in 'insert_knot'
        self.__knot_vector = tuple(new_value)
            
    def increase_degree(self, times: int):
        self.compute_ctrl_points()

    def decrease_degree(self, times: int):
        self.compute_ctrl_points()

    def insert_knot(self, knots: Tuple[float]):
        print(f"Inserting knots {knots}")
        new_knot_vector = list(self.knot_vector)
        for knot in knots:
            new_knot_vector += [knot]
        new_knot_vector.sort()
        self.knot_vector = new_knot_vector
        self.compute_ctrl_points()

    def remove_knot(self, knots: Tuple[float]):
        print(f"Removing knots {knots}")
        new_knot_vector = list(self.knot_vector)
        for knot in knots:
            new_knot_vector.remove(knot)
        self.knot_vector = new_knot_vector
        self.compute_ctrl_points()

    def compute_ctrl_points(self):
        print("I must be called on insertion and remotion")
```

Then I want to the user do it:

```py
mycurve = SplineCurve([0, 0, 1, 1])
print(mycurve.knot_vector)         # (0, 0, 1, 1)
mycurve.knot_vector += (0.5, 0.5)  # This line should called as 'mycurve.insert_knot((0.5, 0.5))'
print(mycurve.knot_vector)         # (0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
mycurve.knot_vector -= (0.5, 1)    # This line should called as 'mycurve.remove_knot((0.5, 1))'
print(mycurve.knot_vector)         # (0, 0, 0.5, 1)
```

For inserting knot, the printed value is correct, but the function `insert_knot` (and `Inserting knots ...` is not printed).

But for `-=` gives the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'tuple' and 'tuple'`, which is normal, cause it's like

```
temp_value = mycurve.knot_vector - (0.5, 1)  # Error here
mycurve.knot_vector = temp_value  # Setter is only called here
```

Calling the argument on `insert_knot` and `remove_knot` should allow also:

```py
mycurve.knot_vector += numpy.array([0.3, 0.7])
mycurve.knot_vector += [0.4, 0.9]
```

Comment: You would need to overload the `+=` operator on the object returned by `knot_vector`. This means that it needs to be a user-defined object and not a tuple.

Comment: @interjay Doing it, it will only change the values of ```knot_vector``` object. If ```insert_knot``` changes something in ```mycurve```(like calling ```compute_ctrl_points```), it won't happen.

Comment: It seems very confusing and error-prone if `x.knot_vector += y` changes things which aren't in `knot_vector`. But if you really want then you can put a reference to the containing object in the `knot_vector` object and then call `insert_knot` on that.

Comment: @interjay Overwrite, not overload.

Comment: @interjay Yes, I agree with you at the point ```x.knot_vector += y``` changes something in ```x``` may be confusing, but I did the same for ```degree``` and it seems very nice. The difference would be only the type (```degree``` is an integer, while ```knot_vector``` is an array of floats). Both concepts (```degree``` and ```knot_vector```) exist only if the curve exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution as proposed @interjay is to create a new class object that can sum with an iterable.

Then there's two possibilities:

1. Call the `curve.insert_knot` on `__iadd__` and `curve.remove_knot` on `__isub__` using indirect reference, and then lose the curve's reference. We can return `None` and `curve.knot_vector setter` does nothing.

> ```py
> class KnotVector(Tuple):
>     def __new__(cls, curve, args: tuple[float]):
>         self = super(KnotVector, cls).__new__(cls, tuple(args))
>         self._curve = curve
>         return self
>     
>     def __iadd__(self, knots: tuple[float]):
>         if self._curve is not None:
>             self._curve.insert_knot(knots)
>             self._curve = None
>         else:
>             return tuple(self) + knots
>
>     def __isub__(self, knots: tuple[float]):
>         if self._curve is not None:
>             self._curve.remove_knot(knots)
>             self._curve = None
>         else:
>             return tuple(self) + knots
>
> class SplineCurve:
>     ...
>     @property
>     def knot_vector(self) -> KnotVector:
>         return KnotVector(self, tuple(self._knot_vector))
>
>     @knot_vector.setter
>     def knot_vector(self, new_knot_vector: Tuple[float]):
>         if new_value is None:
>             return
>         self._knot_vector = tuple(new_knot_vector)
>     ...
> ```
>
> A problem that can happen is assigning `knot_vector` into a variable `myvector`, and then it changes `mycurve` without noticing.
>
> ```py
> mycurve = SplineCurve([0, 0, 1, 1])
> myvector = mycurve.knot_vector
> # ... after many instructions
> myvector += (0.5, 0.5)  # This will change mycurve
> ```

2. Modify in `KnotVector` class to add and remove, and give the information to `mycurve` through `knot_vector setter`, the same way that happens for `degree`:

> ```
> class KnotVector(Tuple):
>     def __new__(cls, args: tuple[float]):
>         return super(KnotVector, cls).__new__(cls, tuple(args))
>     
>     def __iadd__(self, knots: tuple[float]):
>         new_knot_vector = list(self)
>         for knot in knots:
>             new_knot_vector += [knot]
>         new_knot_vector.sort()
>         return tuple(new_knot_vector)
>
>     def __isub__(self, knots: tuple[float]):
>         new_knot_vector = list(self)
>         for knot in knots:
>             new_knot_vector.remove(knot)
>         return tuple(new_knot_vector)
>
> class SplineCurve:
>     ...
>
>     @property
>     def knot_vector(self) -> KnotVector:
>         return KnotVector(self._knot_vector)
>
>     @knot_vector.setter
>     def knot_vector(self, new_knot_vector: Tuple[float]):
>         if self._knot_vector == new_knot_vector:
>             return
>         if self.new_knots_inserted(new_knot_vector):
>             self.insert_knot(self.get_new_knots(new_knot_vector))
>         else:
>             self.remove_knot(self.get_removed_knots(new_knot_vector))
>     ...
> ```